# Unable to search a string using more pager

Tags: ubuntu, string, search, pager, more

I opened a file using the `more` pager,i was trying to find a string in this file using `/` as shown in the figure below,but it is saying that pattern not found even though the string i have searched is present in the file,in the second case when i tried to find `and` string ,it is not showing any thing on hitting `enter`,and just showing the next page on screen.Again the `and` string is present in the file,still it is not found on hitting enter. What wrong am i doing here and why there are two different results with these two different strings

[image: Searching a string <code>random</code>]

[image: Pattern is not found]

[image: Searching another string <code>and</code>]

[image: Nothing happens on pressing enter,it shows the next page on screen]

Comment: In the first case, I think it's just telling you that there is no *further* instance of `random` below the one that's already shown at the top of the screen; in the second case, it's likely paging forward because almost every screen contains `and`. Perhaps you are just surprised because the match is not highlighted - as it would be by default in the `less` pager?

Comment: I have one more, i understand that using `space` we move forward by a screen but i am not able to understand the function of `f` and `b` key in `more` ,how navigation is defined using these two keys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it,it was actually finding the string but the main difference between `more` and `less` is that the string when found in `more` is not highlighted,that's why i was getting confused.For more explanation check the comment section.